# Generic ValueConverter

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm trying to register a custom generic value converter but it's not being picked up in the binding process. What can be wrong. It's based on this manual: https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#dataBinding
When I remove the generics everything works fine.

my generic enum converter:

```
abstract class EnumValueConverter < T extends Enum > implements ValueConverter {
    @Override
    boolean canConvert(Object value) {
        value instanceof String
    }

    @Override
    Object convert(Object value) {
        try {
            T.valueOf(value)
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException illegalArgumentException) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("needs to be one of ${T.values()*.name()} but is: $value")
        }
    }

    @Override
    Class<?> getTargetType() {
        T
    }
}
```

my specific converter:

```
class SomeEnumValueConverter extends EnumValueConverter<SomeEnum>{}
```

registartion in resources.groovy:

```
someEnumValueConverter SomeEnumValueConverter
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a generic in a context like that.  If you create an instance of `SomeEnumValueConverter` and invoke `getTargetType()` on that instance the return value will be `Object`, not `SomeEnum` so the framework doesn't know what type the converter should be used for.

You can override the `getTargetType()` method in SomeEnumValueConverter and return `SomeEnum`.

Comment: Thanks, so is there any way to have that in a more generic way other than duplicating this for every Enum I would like to support?